# How to programmatically disable Windows 8 drag desktop

Tags: c#, fullscreen

I need a full screen app for win 8.1 tablet for visitors. I've disabled all menu from registry, but if they touch the app and push slowly down, then they grab the destop and the windows will be appear.

I set this and works, but not enough:

```
DisableTLCorner
DisableCharmsHint
DisableTRCorner
```

Comment: Is [Kiosk Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx) what you are looking for?

Comment: Just a note on Kiosk Mode, it is only supported in Windows 8.1, not 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any programming trick to achieve what you need. In Windows 8.1 Microsoft added a mode to allow the user to be able to use only an application, this mode is **Kiosk Mode** and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx) is how to enable it.